# My program is not giving the correct output?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, absolute

I'm trying to get the absolute value of -2 to appear on python.

```
   def distance_from_zero(a):

            if type(a) == int or type(a) == float:

                 return abs(a)

            else:

                 return "Nope"

   distance_from_zero(-2)
```

The programs just says "None". I want it to give me the absolute value of -2 or say "nope" is the number is not an int or float.

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Copy paste the code in to this question and format it appropriately. And please explain what "not giving the correct output" means exactly. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Try to print the result: `print(distance_from_zero(-2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `print` to see the output.

```
def distance_from_zero(a):
    if type(a) == int or type(a) == float:
        return abs(a)
    else:
        return "Nope"

print distance_from_zero(-2)
print distance_from_zero('hi')
```

Output:

```
➜  python ./distance.py
2
Nope
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/RwXou3)

Comment: Thanks this gives me the absolute value but I also need it to return "Nope" if the type is not int or float?

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution I needed.

Answer (score 2):

slightly a better way,

```
def distance_from_zero(dist):
    a = 'Nope'
    if isinstance(dist, int) or isinstance(dist, float):
        a = abs(dist)
    return a
```